Does this area51 proposal on "social problem solving" suit cogsci topic?
I've created a proposal in area51 for concrete social conflict resolution. This is not about theory of resolutions but about resolutions of real life conflicts. But I'm in doubt, perhaps this type of questions can be asked here.
Could you please review it and tell me should it be separate site or it suits your topic? 
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94358/social-problem-solving/94470#94470

I can't because I do not have the privilege. Could you please reask it for me?

We in fact have an off-topic close reason:

Questions about the behavior of an individual person are off-topic.
  If you are concerned about a potential medical issue, please seek the
  advice of a medical professional.

At a first glance, it would seem that most questions that would be asked on the new Area51 proposal would fall within that category for this site. We expect questions to be more framed within a scientific perspective.
